# How to throw enemies into a pit in Dwarf Fortress

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I throw goblins or any other creatures into a pit?

I have 3 level pit where I want to throw a variety of enemies into. The lowest level is the actual pit, and spans 6x6 squares. I have specified the zone for this, and picked 'pit'.

The uppermost layer is where the dwarves are supposed to go to throw the enemies into the pit. The enemy would fall through the second layer and then land in the pit. These two layers have a 1x1 hole where the enemies are supposed to fall through. I have specified each of the 1x1 hole to be a channel.

When I want my dwarves to throw a goblin into the pit, I assign the pit to that goblin and the game is supposed to assign a dwarf to handle that action. But nothing happens. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to designate the top of the pit (hole + standing room around it) as a pit zone, not the floor at the bottom.

You can tell if your designation is a legal pit because the zone screen will show a count of how many squares are legal pit locations within your zone. If it doesn't show 1 or more, your pit will not work and will be ignored.

Comment: Okay, so my top most floor has to be the pit zone.